# MVC3: How to improve data query for multi user system

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm coding for a multi users webapp, each user will create and manage a list of "Category" and "Product". So, when I need to get a list of "Category" or "Product" for any user, I have to check:

```
IEnumerable<Categories> results = from x in db.Categories
                                         where String.Compare(x.UserName, User.Identity.Name, true) == 0 
                                         select x;
        return View(results.ToList());
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Categories> results = from x in db.Categories
                                      where String.Compare(x.UserName, User.Identity.Name, true) == 0
                                      select x;
        ViewBag.CatLists = results.ToList();
```

so on,...it is a very bad coding style. And I want to improve this one, but I don't know how to do this.
Thank you for any idea!

Comment: I really hope that the username is a foreign key in the categories table. (or that you do not allow username changes)

Comment: Seems fine, I wouldn't use the user name, I would use an id of some sort. Also I wouldn't use the ViewBag, are you familiar with ViewModels?

Comment: is this linq to sql if it is you should precompile your queries.  Also I am not sure but you may be doing something very bad by using string.Compare function.  You could be pulling down all the records and then executing that function on them to determine if they are equal.  You should take a look at the sql being sent to make sure of that.

Comment: yes, I use the UserName as a foreign key, it can't be changed. The bad thing is I have to rewrite the same query many times...